# Using JS function with parameters in php

Tags: php, javascript, parameters, arguments

The JS function is

```
function func(arg){  
    alert(arg);  
}
```

When I do

```
echo "<div onclick=\"func($arg)\">Text</div>";
```

in php, it doesnt work
but when I do

```
echo "<div onclick=\"func()\">Text</div>";
```

it works and an alert with undefined text pops up.

How do I pass argument?

Comment: What are you trying to pass? In the onclick attribute you need to have valid Javascript. Is `$arg` a PHP variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap `$arg` in quotes. Example:

`echo "<div onclick=\"func('$arg')\">Text</div>";`

(using single quotes around `arg` as you're using double quotes for the string)

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the arguments. e.g.

```
<?php
$foo = 'bar';
?>

echo "function($foo) { ... }";
```

is going to produce the code

```
function(bar) { ... }
```

where `bar` will be interpreted as an undefined variable.

Safest method is to output your PHP variables via json_encode(), to guarantee you're producing syntactically valid javascript. e.g.

```
echo 'function(' . json_encode($foo) . ') { ... }';
```

which would produce (in this case)

```
function ('bar') { ... }
```

Comment: Beat me to it, with a more thorough answer. +1.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this (if $args exists of course)

```
echo '<div onclick="func('.$arg.')">Text</div>';
```